# Transferring data from rows in one Gridview to another

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had this problem for a while now and I have no existing reference for my code. I am transferring a row of data from gridview1 to gridview2, but once I clicked the checkbox and clicked the add button it transfers the data to gridview2 but the selected data isn't removed from gridview1.

I was hoping that when I select a checkbox and clicked the add button it will transfer the data to gridview2 and remove it from gridview1. Can someone help me?

**here is my aspx.cs**

```
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[12] { new DataColumn("prno"), new DataColumn("itemname"), new DataColumn("itemgroupid"), new DataColumn("itemsubgroupid"), new DataColumn("specifications"), new DataColumn("qty"), new DataColumn("uomid"), new DataColumn("expenseid"), new DataColumn("statusid"), new DataColumn("userid"), new DataColumn("inserteddate"), new DataColumn("withquotation") });
        foreach (GridViewRow row in grdPR.Rows)    
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[12].FindControl("chkSelectPerRequest") as CheckBox);
                if (chkRow.Checked)  
                {
                    string prno = row.Cells[0].Text;
                    string itemname = row.Cells[1].Text;
                    string itemgroupid = row.Cells[2].Text;
                    string itemsubgroupid = row.Cells[3].Text;
                    string specifications = row.Cells[4].Text;
                    string qty = row.Cells[5].Text;
                    string uomid = row.Cells[6].Text;
                    string expenseid = row.Cells[7].Text;
                    string statusid = row.Cells[8].Text;
                    string userid = row.Cells[9].Text;
                    string inserteddate = row.Cells[10].Text;
                    string withquotation = row.Cells[11].Text;
             
                    dt.Rows.Add(prno, itemname, specifications, qty, uomid, expenseid, statusid, userid, inserteddate, withquotation);
                    grdPR.Rows.Remove(row);
                 
                    //dt.Rows.Remove(dt[0]);
                  
                    //dt.Rows.Clear();

              
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

**this is the button click**

```
 protected void btnAddPRTemplate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

      AddToPOTemplate();
    

 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have to refresh (bind) gridview1

Comment: I see now, Thank you. I have to use bool too, Thanks!